"One of" type in C++
In SML, which is a dynamic functional language, there's a way to create a "one of" data type
datatype element = NONE | Value of Structure; and now I can use as a return type in function: return either a Structure or NONE
I didn't find any way of doing the same in C++ and I tried using an enum but they only accept constants.

Note C++ is a strongly typed language. So it doesn't have a type that is really like "one of".   There are std::variant and std::any (but I don't recommend using the last one).

Sounds like std::optional though.

And there is std::expected (in C++23). Note you can always let a function return a struct of your own chosing.  But I think @Wyck is on to something too

"One of" is more similar to std::variant. std::optional is more like a "One Of" with a nullvalue and an existing value

@Pepijn Kramer
I don't think it's a characteristic of strongly typed languages, SML is strongly typed.

Decent idiom for initializing an optional to either null or a value? and C++ A function that can return one of two types depending on the accepted value

It sounds like you're asking for std::optional.  The point of this class template is that it may or may not contain a value.  It's similar to a nullable type in C# or a Maybe type in functional languages.
example:
std::optional<int> opt1;  // empty optional
std::optional<int> opt2 = 10;  // optional containing a value
std::optional<int> opt3 = std::nullopt;  // explicitly empty

You can check to see if it has a value and retrieve its value like this:
if (opt2.has_value()) {
    int value = opt2.value();  // or int value = *opt2;
}

An example of returning a value or not from a function would be like this:
std::optional<int> find(int value) {
    if (/* some condition */) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}


That's great, thank you so much!
And this actually reminded me of OPTION in SML:
fun calculate x = if x < 0 then NONE else SOME (value)
and there are functions like valof(option) and isSome(option) which are similar to those in C++.
It's used beautifully in pattern matching in SML

@Ghassen Unfortunately in C++ you'll have to live without pattern matching. You can achieve a lot of the behavior of proper algebraic data types in functional languages with C++, but generally the syntax is going to be cumbersome.

@user17732522 You could answer this question.
